# How to implement an onChange function on a select box in formly with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, onchange, angular-formly

After reading quite a few posts I decided that this ought to work:

```
vm.model.myChange = function(element) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

.. and in the vm.fields:

```
{
"key": "transportation",
"type": "select",
"templateOptions": {
  "label": "How do you get around in the city",
  "valueProp": "name",
  "onChange": "model.myChange()", // ADDED
  "options": [{
    "name": "Car"
  }, {
    "name": "Helicopter"
  }]
}
```

In practice this has no effect, i.e. my function is not called.  The generated form contained no reference to my function either.

I could not find a working example of how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Thx. Paul

Comment: Could you please provide [an example](http://help.angular-formly.com) of this not working? I would expect that your function would be called (though you're not calling it with any arguments, so you're not going to see anything logged to the console).

Comment: here we go http://jsbin.com/veqosejaja/edit?js,console,output

Comment: here you are :-) https://jsbin.com/zeyazo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Great. many thx @kent. I will study and learn ;-) Paul

Comment: @user1712240 could you write the answer and accept it please?

Answer (score 5):

you can do any of these three things:

```
templateOptions: {
   onChange: function($viewValue, $modelValue, $scope) {
   //implement logic here
   };
}
```

OR

```
templateOptions: {
   onChange: callMe()
},
controller: function($viewValue, $modelValue, $scope) {
    $scope.callMe = function() {
    //implement logic here
    };
}
```

OR

```
    templateOptions: {
       onChange: ''
    },
    expressionProperties : {
       'templateOptions.onChange': function($viewValue, $modelValue, $scope) {
       //implement logic here
       };
   }
```

Comment: This (the first option) did not do anything for me; I'm new to formly but I imagine it has something to do with the specific `templateOptions` available in whatever template one happens to be using? Using `change` instead of `onChange`, as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791792/2442167 did work for me.

Answer (score 3):

One way I handled this is having my json fields served from a service.With this one can comfortably call a function.

NB:This is served from a service or a factory

```
var getFields = function () {
    var fields = [
        {
           "key": "transportation",
           "type": "select",
           "templateOptions": {
           "label": "How do you get around in the city",
           "valueProp": "name",
           "onChange": "function(){//Implement your logic}"
           "options": [{
                "name": "Car"
           }, {
             "name": "Helicopter"
           }]
       }
   ] 
};
```