# Formly access to form control value onChange

Tags: angular, forms, material-design, angular-formly

I'm trying to evaluate [Formly](https://formly.dev/). This is my first attempt - I want to call a method when the value of a textarea change. This is the code I tried with - so far it doesn't appear to be working I'm not sure If my syntax for the templateOptions is wrong or if I should be accessing the value of the input different.

```
 form = new FormGroup({});
  model = { defaultText: this.defaultText } ;
  label = this.defaultText ;
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [{
    key: 'editor',
    id: 'editor',
    name: 'editor',
    type: 'textarea',
    templateOptions: {
      placeholder: this.defaultText,
      onChange: this.previewText = this.parseMarkDownText(this.form.get('editor').value),
   //   appearance: 'fill'
    }
  }];
```

Comment: use `change` fn instead of `onChange`.

Answer (score 8):

Oops, I forgot to post my answer. This is what worked.

````
   ngOnInit() {
        this.form = new FormGroup({});
        this.fields = [{
            key: 'editor',
            id: 'editor',
            name: 'editor',
            type: 'textarea',
            defaultValue: this.defaultText,
            templateOptions: {
                rows: 5,
                cos: 50,
                change: (field, $event)=>{ 
                    this.previewText = this.parseMarkDownText(field.form.controls.editor.value);
                },
            }
        }];
    }
    ```
````